# How do I make sure that a Hyperledger Fabric peer is not able to view the database?

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric

I am a Hyperledger Fabric Newbie and I am trying to build my  first project where I will store a government ID database on HyperLedger Fabric. I'll be using CouchDB to store the data.

I want to make sure that the peer(committing or endorsing) is not able to view  the data stored as a local copy on his system by directly browsing to http://localhost:5984/ .

**To view the database he has to query the system using the chaincode only.**

P.S. I am referring  the official documentation of HyperLedger Fabric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would probably include a complex username and password for the CouchDB container specified in the docker-compose.yml file.

You would not publish the port outside the the docker/kubernetes environment - see docker-compose.yml file.

You would protect the whole backend Fabric environment with Firewall zones.

For a production environment you would consider a hosting platform that manages the above for you.